# How to display option values in ng-bind?

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I want to display selected name from `dropdown`. i can see their names
 like `abc, xyz` in `dropdown` but when i choose particular to display on
 form. its `candidate_id` is printing on `Form` .

i want to print that name
 only not id of name. i put `candidate_id` in value because i want to
 store id in db after submitting form.

```
 <select ng-model="empInfo.candidate_name" class="span2">
        <option ng-repeat="x in names4"  value="{{x.candidate_id}}">
              {{x.candidate_name}}
        </option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, for display purpose you want the name and id for DB purposes.
Change in HTML markup :

```
  <select ng-model="empInfo" 
 ng-options="emp.candidate_name for emp in names4"></select>

 <div>id is : {{empInfo.candidate_id}}</div>
 <div>name is : {{empInfo.candidate_name}}</div>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/cOKY3GJIOsWWEqurmlEr?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Change the value attribute of option tag to x.candidate_name.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `value`to :

```
<select ng-model="empInfo.candidate_name" class="span2">
    <option ng-repeat="x in names4"  value="{{x.candidate_name}}">{{x.candidate_name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: it works for me but same time i want to store candidate_id in db on form submit . how to store candidate_id

Answer (score 0):

```
 <select ng-model="empInfo.candidate_name" class="span2">
        <option ng-repeat="x in names4"  value="{{x}}">{{x.candidate_name}}</option>
 </select>{{x}} {{x.candidate_id}}{{x.candidate_name}}
```

While send just take id

Comment: {"candidate_id":"1","candidate_name":"Name1"} it prints like this. i want to print only name like Name1 and to store id of Name1

Comment: Try this ng-bind="empInfo.candidate_name.candidate_name" or ng-model="cname" ng-bind="cname.candidate_name"